# Why does `LD_DEBUG=libs` fail to display a library that loaded in an application?

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, ld, shared-objects

### Background:

I am trying to discover where `libqbscore.so` is loaded from, and when it happens. When I set `LD_DEBUG=libs` and run the program, `/bin/qtcreator`, I do not find `libqbscore.so` amidst the debug.

If however, I set `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libqbscore.so`, then I will start finding its occurences in the output.

### Question:

- Why would `LD_DEBUG` fail to display a library it is clearly loading?
- Is it perhaps simply silent on libraries without debugging symbols?
- How can I fix this so I can determine the origin of `libqbscore.so` when I run QtCreator?

Thanks.

Comment: obviously, if you force the load with LD_PRELOAD, it will load it, but that does mean your software *needs* it not it was linked with it

Comment: BTW, what lets you think that libqbscore.so is loaded?

Comment: @OznOg I know the code executes due to seeing a particular function in action. I double checked however by removing the libqbscore libraries from `/usr/lib` and expectedly, qtcreator displays `Fatal qbs error: The qbs process sent unexpected data` -- QtCreator does not crash however, but its qbs plugin is non-functional.

Comment: gt-creator must be loading this dynamially with dlopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the qtcreator process does not load the libqbscore.so. The qbs child process loads it.

Because [Qt Creator](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator) and [Qbs](https://github.com/qbs/qbs) are open source projects, their interactions can be analyzed by analyzing the source codes.

Comment: `reverse engineering it` -- I am developing for it actually, however I have been unable to set breakpoints in gdb for it, which is making development tricky. This question was to give me a clue on why that was happening. Now I need to figure out how to get this child process to work with gdb.

Comment: I will edit the answer because I didn't mean to be offensive. Although it's off the topic, I recommend you to contact other Qbs developers. As a general debugging hint, you can attach to an existing process with gdb.(```raise(SIGTRAP)``` will be useful on the qbs side.)

Comment: Already have, and thanks for the tip.